# Serversocket accepts more connections as it should from the same client

Tags: java, sockets, httpresponse

I want to make a simple http response without much to it, but it somehow screwes up. It makes around 3 connections but sometimes sending the 2nd or 3rd response before the request when i checked it with Wireshark. I am confused big time!

Here is the code:

```
public static int letThrough() throws IOException
{
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(80);
    Socket connectionSocket = null;  
    while(running)
    {
        connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Client: " + connectionSocket.getPort());

        makeSession(connectionSocket);
    }
    serverSocket.close();
    return 1;
}

static public Runnable makeSession(Socket connectionSocket)
{
    Runnable rSession = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
            String clientIp = connectionSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
            System.out.println("Client verbunden... (" + clientIp + ")");
            PrintWriter oPWriter;

            oPWriter = new PrintWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream(), false);

            System.out.println("Streams erstellt...");

            Date today = new Date();
            Thread.sleep(10);
            oPWriter.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            oPWriter.println("Content-Type: text/html");
            oPWriter.println("Server: Bot");
            // this blank line signals the end of the headers
            oPWriter.println("");
            // Send the HTML page
            oPWriter.println("<H1>Welcome to the Ultra Mini-WebServer</H2><br><H2>"+today.toString());
            oPWriter.flush();
            oPWriter.close();

            connectionSocket.shutdownOutput();
            while(connectionSocket.isOutputShutdown() == false)
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            connectionSocket.close();
            while(connectionSocket.isClosed() == false)
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }

            }
            catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };

    new Thread(rSession).start();
    return rSession;
}
```

I tried already some things, like the last two while-loops with sleep. Any Idea how i even can debug this?

Comment: Your title is incomprehensible, and ditto your question. You're never reading the request. Shutdown before close is redundant, and the loops checking whether the output is shutdown or the socket is closed are pointless. Remove them. They will never execute. The line terminator in HTTP is `\r\n`, not the platform default.

Answer (score -1):

Problem found! There was no real Problem with my code, it was the stupid chrome browser establishing connnections without using them. Or maybe there used for secret things that i cant see.